# Render XML in browser with XDocument

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I am creating an XML file using the below code

```
Private Sub GetXML As XDocument
Dim XD As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><Customers></Customers>

For each c in mycustomers
 XD.Root.Add(<Customer>.....</Customer>
Next
End Function
```

I am trying to use the XD object to display the XML produced in a browser. So i started by using the Save method which produces the XML to see if there are any problems - the file looks correct. So i add the below declaration

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml"
    Literal1.Text =  GetXML.ToString
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

This doesnt produce the XML in the browser (the way the Save function produces it when creating the file), so further reading leads me to add the line

```
XD.Save(Response.write)
```

which shows XML in the browser window but doesnt show the declaration  which leads me to believe im still doing something wrong. I then change this line to

```
Literal1.Text = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & GetXML.ToString
```

Which again doesnt work. Although im new with Linq to XML i cant seem to get this one working the way i want?

EDIT

I just tried

```
    Dim wr As New StringWriter
....
    XD.Save(wr)

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml"
    Response.Write(wr.GetStringBuilder.ToString)
```

Again this showed the XML but no declaration.....

Comment: You have to set the content type.

Comment: Already done Response.ContentType = "application/xml"

Comment: Forget about LINQ to XML for a sec and try to produce hard coded XML file to the client. Does it work?

Comment: Yes i have a hardcode XML file which i can view in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Use `XDeclaration` to include declartion in your XML Document.

```
Dim doc = New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "no"), New XElement("Customer", "..."))
Dim sw = New StringWriter()
doc.Save(sw)
Console.Write(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString())
```